# How to remove the spaces of a varchar value in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a procedure which retrieves all the procedure scripts from a database defined.

The problem  am getting is values with the blank spaces

for exampl :

when i executes the procedure i am getting the char(13) + char(10)'s (ie: Spaces between each print)

```
Print @IsSQl5 


Print @IsSQl6                  


Print @IsSQl7
```

I tried with replace function but it doesn't works fine How to solve this ?

Comment: they're not spaces but char(13) + char(10) 's

Comment: maybe you can show procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mitch Wheat said they are not spaces, char(13) and char(10) are line endings (Cr+Lf).
To remove them:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE([value having the char(13/10)], char(13), ''), [value having the char(13/10)], char(10), '')
```